# Why flexbox child not inheriting parent width when overflow is given

Tags: flexbox

why parent width is not getting inherited to child on overflow...for demo i have added a background color

Please reduce the viewport to less than 400px to produce the result
https://codepen.io/prinjuk/pen/WNoKNaX

```
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
    </ul>
  </div
      <div>
    <ul>
      <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
        <li>efsfs</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

.flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  max-width:400px;
  overflow:auto;
}
ul{
  flex-direction:row;
  display:flex;
  background:#cdcdcd;
  
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: @RomanMkrtchian to have the background color to wrap the entire content